# Update DropDownList control after inserting an item with a detailsview

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, detailsview, html-select

I have an update panel that includes a dropdownlist control and a detailsview control.  The dropdownlist is populated by a sqldatasource control which grabs the data from a table called Places (just a list of venues).  The detailsview is insert mode only and inserts places into the database table that populates the dropdownlist.  I am trying to allow someone to insert a new place inside the update panel and have the dropdownlist refreshed at the same time so the user will see all places in the dropdownlist, including the one they just added with the details view.  Right now, the detailsview is adding the place to the database properly but not updating the dropdownlist.  If I refresh the page after adding a new place, the droplist updates with the new place.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are both controls inside the same update panel?

Comment: Yes, both of the controls are inside the update panel.

Comment: @thenextmogul if the suggested answer worked for you then plz mark it as accepted answer to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer was posted before any code was posted in the question.

This also assumes both controls are inside the update panel.

In the event handler for Updating or Inserting for your DetailsView control, you need to add the following code:

```
MyDropDownList.DataBind()
```

And, worst case scenario, you can do this if the update panel is causing you problems. It's not the greatest performance-wise though.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawURL)
```